# CentOS 7 with VM version 8

Tags: vmware

Can I create CentOS7 with VM version 8 on vmware. (using vSphere Client)?

[vmware compatiblity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1F06.png)
Best Regards,
Fred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware (hardware) version 8 lines up with ESXi 5.0, so you won't be able to select CentOS7 on the drop-down box. This just means that it's not certified to work on that version of ESXi. You can still install CentOS7 though, you'll just need to select one of the "Linux Other" guest types instead.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Yes, not able to select CentOS 7 on the drop-down. So, I just have to use Linux Other. I have production servers (RHEL6) on the same ESXI with network adapter VMXNET3 . If I select Linux Other, i cannot select VMXNET3 adapter. Only E1000 is available. Will it be safe to create Linux Other with E1000 on the same ESXi?

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. The E1000 works just fine with CentOS 7 and there won't be any confusion with other VMs using different NIC types.